# Determine os valores de M e N

Tags: c, assembly

M e N são constantes defenidas por #define

```
int mat1[M][N];
int mat2[N][M];

int sum_element(int i, int j) {
return mat1[i][j] + mat2[i][j];
}
```

Suponhamos que o codigo acima gera o seguinte em assembly:

```
sum_element:


pushl %ebp

movl %esp,%ebp

movl 8(%ebp),%eax

movl 12(%ebp),%ecx

sall $2,%ecx

leal 0(,%eax,8),%edx

subl %eax,%edx

leal (%eax,%eax,4),%eax

movl mat2(%ecx,%eax,4),%eax

addl mat1(%ecx,%edx,4),%eax

movl %ebp,%esp

popl %ebp

ret
```

Comment: Qual a sua dúvida?